# Flutter: Drawing Arcs. How can I fix my circles orientation and split it as I need?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm passing a canvas arc to Google Maps via onLongPress. The whole start angle radian thing is throwing me off. I'd like the north point of my circle to be 0 degrees, and the south point to be 180. I want to be able to plot three separate pieces of the pie, each being 120 degrees. But also, i'd like to be able to define this range. For example, 270 to 290 degrees. Kind of like this (Sector of the Disk):

[image]

If at all possible, I want to be able to define distance as well. So my arc will not only show my input starting and ending radius, but will extend by meters or miles.
Here's what I have so far:

```
Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromCanvas(int width, int height) async {
  final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
  var paint1 = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xff63aa65)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 5;
  canvas.drawArc(Offset(180, 180) & Size(300, 300),
      0,
      6,
      true,
      paint1);
  final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(width, height);
  final data = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  return data.buffer.asUint8List();
}

Future < ui.Image > loadImage(List < int > img) async {
  final Completer < ui.Image > completer = new Completer();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

Also, here's where things start to get messed up again:

```
  Future _addMarkerLongPressed(LatLng latlang) async {
    
    final Uint8List markerIcon = await getBytesFromCanvas(500, 500);
    final Marker marker = Marker(icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon));
    
    setState(() {
      var markerIdVal = markers.length + 1;
      String mar = markerIdVal.toString();
      Marker marker = Marker(
        anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
        markerId: MarkerId(mar),
        draggable: true,
        position: latlang,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon),
      );
      markers[MarkerId(mar)] = marker;
    });
  }
```

Edit: This is pretty frustrating. Even after converting degress to radians and accounting for east being my 0, i'm still off and it doesn't look right.... Maybe I'd be better off stamping a PNG of a sector than fussing with arcs. Or maybe I can do this somehow with polygons? Hope I can pick one of your brains about this...

Edit2: Would it be possible to stamp a polygon in the shape of a triangle at a specific latlng?

Comment: For three separate ranges, use the range `offsetTheta` to `offsetTheta + 2 * math.pi / 3`. If you want `n` distinct pieces, use the range `offsetTheta` to `offsetTheta + 2 * math.pi / n`. In both cases, `offsetTheta` is the starting angle where you want the arc to begin. If you want this to be "North," try using -pi/2 for the value (I haven't tested, but I think it should work).

Comment: so by having canvas.drawArc(Offset(0, 0) & Size(300, 300),
      2 * math.pi / 3,
      2,

I'm pulling approx 2 of 6 sections of the pie there? This is resulting in a south arc and it looks great. I'm not sure how to implement offsetTheta here. I set it like so: canvas.drawArc(Offset(-pi/2, -pi/2) but there's no change

Comment: is there any way i can simply pass degrees as strings for this? like, i want to draw 120 to 160 degrees... and have it draw an arc for those parameters? :|

Comment: Yeah. That wouldn't be too hard. If the parameters were numbers that would be better but a simple conversion to radians would do the trick (degrees*2pi/360)

Comment: I would like to mention, however, that it is typically better to just "think" in radians. I used to hate them back in highschool since fractions (of 2pi) are harder to compare than integers, so knowing which angles are which and which are bigger than others always requires some thought. That being said, radians are extraordinarily useful when dealing with the unit circle and are almost a necessity in calculus to keep the math simple.

Comment: And as far as making a function that takes the inputs in degrees: if you insist on degrees & your own starting point (what I referred to as offsetTheta), consider using an extension method. This would allow you to call it like a normal method on the canvas object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but this works. Be sure to flatten icons. Converted to radius:

```
num degreesToRads(num deg) {
  return (deg * pi) / 180.0;
}


canvas.drawArc(Offset(0, 0) & Size(500, 500), degreesToRads(90), 2.09439666667, 
    true, paint1);
canvas.drawArc(Offset(0, 0) & Size(500, 500), degreesToRads(210), 2.09439666667, 
    true, paint1);
canvas.drawArc(Offset(0, 0) & Size(500, 500), degreesToRads(330), 2.09439666667, 
    true, paint1);
```